# Broken links in the ReadyAPI HTML test results generated by testrunner.bat

Tags: ready-api

In Windows, using ReadyAPI version 3.48

When running a ReadyAPI project using testrunner.bat, there are broken links in the generated HTML test report, if the project has a period character "." in its name. The reason that the links are broken is that the period in the project name has been replaced with a "/", in these links.

E.g., the link is "file:///C:/test-results/Project1/0/package-summary.html" while it should be "file:///C:/test-results/Project1.0/package-summary.html". The second link works, since a Project1.0 directory has been created in the test-results directory.

How to reproduce:

1 - Create a project that has a period in its name (e.g. Project1.0)

2 - Run the tests through the commandline, using testrunner.bat with the flags -r -j -I -f  "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report"

3 - Open the index.html on a browser

Is there some way to avoid this, other than renaming the project to remove/replace the period character?

Comment: If you have a ReadyAPI license, you can file a bug at [ReadyAPI: New Support Request](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/message/).